# java script error on moving the jquery references to the asp.net master page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I use jquery and I see that currently, Jquery is given a reference in every content page.
I am planning to move all the references to the master page so that it will be easy to update them when its needed.

So , I remove the jquery references from the content page and place them in the head section of the master page as shown below :

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="App_Themes/masterStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ExtraHeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

When I run the application I get the following error :

```
JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

From my research online this is the right way to do it .. but I get the error. Can anyone help me and point out whats wrong or what needs to be done ?

Comment: First load `jquery-1.9.1.js` than load `jquery-ui.min.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the jquery script tag above the jquery ui script tag and remove one of the jquery ui references since you don't need to include them twice:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link href="App_Themes/masterStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ExtraHeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

jQuery is undefined since the jquery ui library is trying to use the jQuery reference before it is defined in the jquery-1.9.1.js file.

Answer (score 1):

First, change the order of the call to jQuery UI and jQuery library, all library or plugin that use jQuery need that defined jQuery before you call it, this is for all libraries or framewors:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then so that you can see in your code you are calling twice a jQuery UI, check this and also if you are calling twice a jQuery or other libraries:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling jQuery ui library before jQuery library is loaded

your code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

change it to

call jQuery library file first

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I did :). The other answer actually pointed out another flaw I had in my code . So although both answers gave me the right solution , I marked that one as the answer and I gave an up vote to you.